# VBScript Object Required error when renaming files

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a script that renames multiple Excel files. If the file has "TEMP" in its name I want to change "TEMP" to the date from an input box.

The Script works until I get to the For-loop. I get an

> Object Required :'C:\users\jspfu\sourc' error on line 23, Code 800A01A8

error. I am really new to VBScript and I basically copied this code from a YouTube video, well the For-loop part anyway.

Here's my script so far:

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO,FileLoc, UsrDate, Msg, File, Oldname, NewFileName, FoldName

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FileLoc = "C:\Users\jspfu\source\XL_Files"
UsrDate= Inputbox("Enter the Date", "Date")  
FoldName = FSO.GetFolder(FileLoc)

If IsNumeric(UsrDate) and UsrDate<>"" then
Msg = Msgbox ("is this " & UsrDate & " Correct",VBYesNo, "Verify Date")
end if  

Do While Msg <> 6
  If Msg = 7 Then
    UsrDate= Inputbox("Enter the Date", "Date")
        Msg = Msgbox ("is this " & UsrDate & " Correct",VBYesNo, "Verify Date")

    ElseIf Not IsNumeric(UsrDate) or UsrDate= "" then
        UsrDate= Inputbox("Enter the Date", "Date")

End If  
Loop

For each File in FoldName.files
    Oldname = FileLOC & File.name
    NewFileName = replace(Fname, "TEMP", Date)
    FSO.MoveFile Fname, NewFileName
Next
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. Use `Set` to get an object reference for `FoldName`: `Set FoldName = FSO.GetFolder(FileLoc)`
2. Use `File.Name` instead of `MoveFile` to rename your file directly

Here's what your loop should look like:

```
For Each File In FoldName.Files
    NewFileName = Replace(File.Name, "TEMP", UsrDate)
    If NewFileName <> File.Name Then
        File.Name = NewFileName
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you @Etienne Laneville!! It works and it's amazing! Again Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad it works. Please mark question as answered when you have a chance!